# String is different when written and saved in variable

Tags: php

Okay, so I have this confusing problem with a string. I'm using a loop to construct the string, and I use `print_r($exclude)` to see the result. The output of the string is:

101,102,135

... which is correct. Then I'm trying to use `$exclude` in an argument-array for a WordPress-query:

`'terms' => array($exclude),`

In short this should exclude posts from the categories with ID's mentioned above. But this does not work as intended. **Unless** if I write the numbers directly like this, it works:

`'terms' => array(101,102,135),`

So what is the difference between the `$exclude`-string and writing the numbers manually...!?

Comment: `'terms' => explode(',', $exclude)`

Comment: The difference is that when you use `array($exclude)` where `$exclude` is a string, it will create an array with that string as an item instead of array with numbers.

Comment: As you said, `$exclude` is a string, while `array(101,102,135)` is an array of numbers. They are not the same thing. @Federkun"s suggestion should fix it

Comment: Thank you! Clearly I need to read more up on this. Works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
'terms' => array($exclude)
```

Your `terms` array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101,102,135
)
```

**Solution**

```
'terms' => explode(',', $exclude)
```

`$exclude` becomes

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101
    [1] => 102
    [2] => 135
)
```

You are assigning a string to the 0-th key in array, whereas you should be passing array elements.

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will split up your string into an array based on a passed `delimiter` (in your case a comma).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **explode** function of php.

Try below code :

```
'terms' => explode(',', $exclude)
```

Refer this link for more details - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: Sure will do, but "You can accept an answer in 9 minutes" :o)

Comment: your should at least write _why_ you need to do that

Comment: Wow, begging for acceptance within one minute of posting.

Answer (score 1):

In your case if you `print_r` `array($exclude)`
it will give

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101,102,135
)
```

what you need is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101,
    [1] => 102,
    [2] => 135
)
```

ie, an array with those numbers as array elements
so just do `'terms' => explode(',', $exclude)` and you will be good to go...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php